# What files and folders should I ignore when I've created a java web project with maven on netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7

When I create a project on NetBeans 8.2 with Maven like this:

[image]

How should be a .gitignore content for this type of projects Java EE 7 o Java SE created with maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple resources from [**`github/gitignore`**](https://github.com/github/gitignore).
For instance:

- [Maven.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Maven.gitignore)
- [`Java.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore)